# Why aren't these images lining up with the top of the page?

Tags: html, css

The top of my page looks like this (blue bit at the top is the bottom of my bookmarks bar):

[image: top of page]

I have a wrapper div holding two imgs (left, right) and a div. I want these three things to all hug the top of the page and line up. I thought adding `display: inline` would do it, but that didn't work. Now I'm stumped.

CSS:

```
body {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

#main{
  display: inline;
}

p {
  font-family:"Open Sans",sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#img1{
  float:left;
}

#img2{
  float:right;
}

.design-img {
  /*border:1px red;*/
  display: inline;
  top:0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"> </meta>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/raphael.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='container'>
      <img src='go.jpg'/ id='img1' class='design-img'>
      <div id='main'>
        <h1>Table of Contents</h1>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <img src='go.jpg'/ id='img2' class='design-img'>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please make a fiddle?

In the meanwhile, seems like `#img2{
  float:left;
}` might do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#main {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This should do the trick.

Look for the differences between `inline` and `inline-block`

Answer (score 1):

Put this css may this help you..

```
#img1{  width:30%; float:left;}
#img2{ width:30%; float:right;}
h1{ margin:0; width:40%;float:left;}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have #img2 after the main div in the source, which means it starts further down than the first image. Floating it to the right won't make it move up on the page!

One solution is to move the `<img>` up to the top, near the first `<img>`, so that the main div comes after.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#main {
  display: inline;
}
p {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#img1 {
  float: left;
}
#img2 {
  float: right;
}
.design-img {
  /*border:1px red;*/
  display: inline;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <img src='https://placehold.it/150x150' id='img2' class='design-img'>
  <img src='https://placehold.it/150x150' id='img1' class='design-img'>
  <div id='main'>
    <h1>Table of Contents</h1>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

No changes to the css.

By the way, you have an error in your source: a stray `/` in the `<img>` tag. Under some circumstances, this may cause the error correcting routines to think this is the end of the `<img>` tag. So remove those.